# subgradient calculus

Tags: convex-analysis

I have to calculate a subgradient of the following function

$$
p(x) = \max\{e(Cy-Cx)\ :\ Cy \geq Cx, y \in X\},
$$

where $C$ is a $p\times n$ matrix and $X$ is a convex polyhedral set.
It is a non-differentiable function. In some works, it is claimed that to calculate a subgradient of this function, one first writes the dual of the problem defining the function and then calculates a subgradient of this dual. But since I'm not too familiar with convex analysis, I did not understand why we need the dual and is it possible to calculate directly?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what $e$ is, but if you need a subgradient of a maximum of convex functions, you can take a subgradient of one of the functions where the maximum is achieved, e.g. if
$$
p(x) = \max_i f_i(x)
$$
and $p(x) = f_{i_0}(x)$ with $g\in\partial f_{i_0}(x)$, then $g\in\partial p(x)$.